# CA1001 reported on static method in extension class

Tags: c#, async-await, code-analysis, dotnet-httpclient

I have a methods of an extension class that generate [CA1001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182172.aspx)

The warning: "Warning   CA1001  Implement IDisposable on 'ImageSourceExtensions.d__8' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'HttpClient'."

The method:

```
 private static async Task<Stream> GetByteArrayAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken token) {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, token);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            }
        }
```

I have several instances of CA1001 warnings for similar extension methods. The options I can think of:

1) Ignore them using [SuppressMessage]

2) Hold the disposable in a class instance that implements IDisposable and pass them into the extension

Suppressing them feels like the right think for me, but any input to the contrary is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't "this" keyword be used?

Comment: If by "extension class" this is supposed to be an extension method, you are missing the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be disposing `HttpClient` anyway, make it a static reference and re-use it, that's what it's designed to do. Constantly recreating them [can lead to performance issues](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). If you get CA1001 for `HttpClient`, you should absolutely suppress that one.